# Joomla 3.0+ Create PDF from HTML content

Tags: php, pdf, joomla

So I am trying to convert a certain type of page view into PDF (and also CSV's but thats another hurdle). The tricky part is that I am using Joomla 3.0 so the ever popular PhocaPDF extension will not work.

So far I have tried using http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views, but it ends up throwing errors when referring to `JRENDER()`.

Also I have tried using this extension
http://rootprogress.com/index.php/downloads/root-pdf-content

Which I can get to work but only for the article view. I can tell that this plug-in gets its code using DOMPDF and also grabs the $article from JOOMLA! so I have no idea where it is grabbing the $article variable from (so I can reassign it to my new view).

Has anyone had any success with implementing a PDF generator in Joomla 3.0?

Comment: Are we talking about a custom component you are developing or you just want to add the posibility to print articles? Maybe try to be as specific as possible on what is the flow...

Comment: Well I am trying to add the functionality for users to download articles as a PDF, like they had in Joomla 1.5. I have no interest in releasing it as a component and really just want the code for a specific site. Also the ROOT pdf component does this but it will only will do it for pages that contain ?view=article, I am using many different views but I want it to only appear on a custom view.

Comment: Potentially helpful for your CSV task: [How to create a custom script to force the download of a .csv file that is generated in real time?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24285/12352)

Answer (score 0):

The PDF functionality that used to be there in V1.5 was removed in V1.6, see [Changes from 1.5 to 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Content_Parameter_Specifications_for_Version_1.6#Changes_from_Version_1.5). I don't think anybody put it back in for later versions. You can use a [third party component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/print-a-pdf) if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but every plug-in I have found doesn't work with 3.0+ yet. I guess I will just have to wait or try to help with the development on one.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 3.3 has the option to print articles, you have just to enable it.
Then if you're browsing with Google Chrome you can easily print the page as PDF.